# Prevent IOKit driver down in "kextunload" unless some clients remains connected

Tags: c++, macos, iokit, kernel-extension, xnu

I've got IOKit base Driver/Deamons project with relationship of one to many (meaning multiple clients attached to single driver).

The core driver is an IOKit object derived from `IOService` and is also the provider of driver clients derived from `IOUserClient`. Those are the agents of user-space clients (one per user-space client)

My goal was to prevent driver from unload in case of `kextunload` command with root privileges, So that only when the last client disconnect (process terminate or call `IOServiceClose`), the driver will be closed automatically (without the need to do `kextunload` manually)

In order to check what IOKit commands i need to disable/postphone, I've wrapped the basid `IOService` callbacks with the relevant print message and observed the logs in a scenario of running `kextunload` where 2 clients are connected:

```
kernel: (driver) virtual bool com_osxkernel_driver::terminate(IOOptionBits)
kernel: (driver) virtual bool com_osxkernel_driverClient::terminate(IOOptionBits)
kernel: (driver) virtual bool com_osxkernel_driverClient::terminate(IOOptionBits)
kernel: (driver) virtual void com_osxkernel_driverClient::stop(IOService *)
kernel: (driver) virtual void com_osxkernel_driverClient::stop(IOService *)
kernel: (driver) virtual void com_osxkernel_driver::stop(IOService *)
```

--

It seems that even if I take reference from each `IOUserClient` on its provider, and releasing those reference on `IOUserClient::clientClose`
, the `kextunload` command still succeed.

The only way I've found to achieve my goal, is in postponing the `::terminate` command and call it explicitly from `::clientClose`.

So i removed the call to `IOService::terminate` and instead called it from `IOUserClient::clientClose()`. 
Here the relevant code :

```
IOReturn com_osxkernel_driverClient::clientClose() 
{
    myProvider->release();
    return super::terminate(kIOServiceSynchronous) ? kIOReturnSuccess : kIOReturnError;
}


bool com_osxkernel_driverClient::terminate(IOOptionBits options) {
    os_log_info(g_logger,"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return true;
}
```

I'd like to know if there are any, less hacky ways of preventing `kextunload` from succeeding and controlling the timing of driver unload.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the `kextunload` source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/kext_tools/kext_tools-502.1.5/kextunload_main.c.auto.html), you'll see it calls down into `IOCatalogueTerminate()`. In the kernel, this eventually makes its way into the `IOCatalogue::_terminateDrivers()` function. (IOCatalogue.cpp in the xnu sources) There you'll see that the following is run for every IOKit class instance belonging to the kext being unloaded:

```
if ( !service->terminate(kIOServiceRequired|kIOServiceSynchronous) ) 
{
    ret = kIOReturnUnsupported;
    break;
}
```

This indicates that the only way to stop your kext's IORegistry entries is indeed by returning false from `terminate()`.

Whether hard-blocking it like this is a good idea is of course another question entirely. I would recommend you only do this if unloading would endanger the stability of the operating system. Consider that `kextunload` requires root privileges, so in most cases it would be preferable to simply handle the termination of services and user clients cleanly in your userspace code.

If you do return false from `terminate()`, you will also need to be careful about not blocking termination for legitimate reasons. (For example if it's a device driver, the nub your driver matched, e.g. `IOUSBInterface` may try to `terminate()` your driver instance if the device is hot-unplugged.)

Comment: Thanks for the help here.. just where did you find the source code of kextnuload.. perhaps you can post the link here?

Comment: @osxUser I've added the kextunload source link to the answer.